# Convert javascript code into Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert this code below into Jquery?

```
document.getElementsByName("autosubmit")[0].click(); // SUBMIT FORM
```

It should look like this code below.

```
$("#dateForm").submit();
```

Element Name is from `<input type="submit" name="autosubmit">`

Any help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('input[type="submit"][name="autosubmit"]').trigger('click');
```

### OR

If you have multiple elements with `name=autosubmit` you can use [**:first selector**](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
$('input[type="submit"][name="autosubmit"]:first').trigger('click');
```

As per comment

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"][name="autosubmit"]').trigger('click');
}, 2000);
```

Comment: you can just use $('input[name="autosubmit"]').trigger('click');

Comment: @satpal How to set the timer before the trigger? I want to delay the trigger for just a 2 seconds.

Comment: @user3097736, Use `setTimeout(function(){
  $('input[type="submit"][name="autosubmit"]').trigger('click');
 }, 2000);`

Answer (score 2):

Give your form an id and submit with:

```
$("#yourFormId").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code below:

```
$('input[name=autosubmit]:eq(0)').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("input[name='autosubmit']").submit();
```